# widening conversion not implicit when used with 'object' type?

Tags: c#-4.0

The C# MSDN documentation states that widening conversions are implicit and dont require an explicit cast. Accordingly, I find that the following code works without giving any errors:

```
public void MyMethod(int x)
{
    float f = x;  //widening conversion, works implicitly as expected.
    ...
}
```

But, the following does not seem to work, even though this also appears to me to fall under the category of a widening conversion.

```
public static void MyMethod(int x)
{
        object o = x; // implicit conversion - works.
        float f = (float)o; // implicit conversion expected here also - but doesnt work...
}
```

In the above second piece of code, I would expect an implicit conversion to happen from the int data stored in 'o' to the type specified in the explicit cast(float). But this doesnt happen and this code throws an InvalidCastException. Why is this so? I can understand an exception being thrown when 'o' is assigned to 'f' without any cast. But if a cast is specified explicitly and converting to that cast requires an implicit conversion (i.e. int to float) which is supported by the language, why is an exception thrown ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

casts do different things at different times. This line:

```
float f = (float)o;
```

Is not attempting to change the type of `o` - it's attempting to unbox a `float`. Unfortunately, you can only (within a few wiggles<sup>1</sup>) unbox the same type of value that was boxed - a boxed `int` has to be unboxed as an `int`.

You would instead have to do:

```
float f = (int)o;
```

Where the `(int)` is performing the unbox, and then the implicit conversion can occur from `int` to `float`, as per your first example.

For more, read [Boxing and Unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx):

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type `object` or to any interface type implemented by this value type. When the CLR boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a `System.Object` and stores it on the managed heap. Unboxing extracts the value type from the object. Boxing is implicit; unboxing is explicit...

---

<sup>1</sup> There are some rules about `Enum`s and their underlying type which I can't remember and won't ever deliberately use.

Comment: Isn't `(float)` redundant (in your second code block) given the first example OP gives? i.e. implicit conversion. Also, `Convert.ToSingle` might be better for general purpose some-type-of-number-to-float conversions.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - true, I've re-written to remove the explicit `float` conversion.